# Terminology Numerator Baye's Rule?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, terminology, bayes

I am considering this formulation of Baye's Rule

$\mathrm{Pr}(\theta | D) = \frac {\mathrm{Pr}(\theta)\mathrm{Pr}(D|\theta)}{\int \mathrm{Pr}(D|\theta)\mathrm{Pr}(\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta}$

Is there a term for the numerator? ie product of prior and likelihood?

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 3):

Numerator is $\Pr(D|\theta) \Pr(\theta) = \Pr(D, \theta)$ so it is **joint probability**. Or, if you'd like to keep connection with Bayes' rule, you can call it **unnormalized posterior**.